# what is the problem with oauth 2.0 and how open id connect fixes it?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I read the [article](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/07/29/fixing-oauth-2-0-with-openid-connect/) by Dominick Baier and what he says in his article that there are problems with Oauth 2.0 and Open Id connect fixes it.

Since, I'm new to Oauth and Opend Id, not sure what are the problems with Oauth and how does Open Id fixes it?

Anybody can shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

A good read is here https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/ :

> The OAuth 2.0 specification defines a delegation protocol that is
>   useful for conveying authorization decisions across a network of
>   web-enabled applications and APIs. OAuth is used in a wide variety of
>   applications, including providing mechanisms for user authentication.
>   This has led many developers and API providers to incorrectly conclude
>   that OAuth is itself an authentication protocol and to mistakenly use
>   it as such. Let's say that again, to be clear:
>
> OAuth 2.0 is not an authentication protocol.
>
> Much of the confusion
>   comes from the fact that OAuth is used inside of authentication
>   protocols, and developers will see the OAuth components and interact
>   with the OAuth flow and assume that by simply using OAuth, they can
>   accomplish user authentication. This turns out to be not only untrue,
>   but also dangerous for service providers, developers, and end users.
>
> This article is intended to help potential identity providers with the
>   question of how to build an authentication and identity API using
>   OAuth 2.0 as the base. Essentially, if you're saying "I have OAuth
>   2.0, and I need authentication and identity", then read on.